# Problema con punteros en C

Tags: c, matrices, punteros

mi problema es el siguiente: tengo el siguiente código

```
char v = 65;
char k = 65;
char* un = calloc(2, sizeof(char));

for (int i = 0; (25*i < dot) && (i <= 25); i++){
    un[0] = v;
    for (j = 0; (j <= 25) && ((j + (25*i)) < dot); j++){
        un[1] = k;
        strcpy(var[i][j], un);
        printf("%d %d var[0][6] = %s\n", i,j,var[0][6]);

        if((j + 25*i + 1) < dot){
            fprintf(f, " + ");
        }

        k++;
    }

    if((j + 25*i + 1) >= dot){
        fprintf(f, ", t) :-");
        break;
    }
    v++;
    k = 65;
}
```

Lo que pasa es que las celdas de

> var[0][6]
>   se cambia al valor de 
>   var[1][0]

y así sucesivamente. 
Lo que quiero es que esto no ocurra. Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo nada. ¿Podrías darnos un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y como esperas la salida? Así podremos entender tu problema, edita la pregunta para agregar cualquier otro dato pertinente :)

Comment: Lo que pretendo es realizar una tabla en la que la celda [0][0] sea "AA", la [0][1] "AB" y asi sucesivamente. En lo vertical seria la celda [1][0] "BA"...

Comment: Al terminar el algoritmo me encuentro con que la celda [0][6] contiene el mismo valor que la [1][0], es decir "BA",la [0][7]  contiene el [1][1], es decir, "BB", etc...